# Безопасность использования сессий

Tags: php, алгоритм, безопасность, сессия

Есть скрипт простой авторизации:

Пользователь вводит логин, пароль и капчу. По AJAX это дело отправляется в пхп скрипт, который из БД достает пароль пользователя имя которого равно введенному, если они совпадают, то в сессию записывается логин и идет редирект в ЛК. Если пользователь заходит в ЛК и у него не зарегистрирована сессия с именем, то его выкидывает обратно в форму. Если зарегистрирована то из БД берутся остальные данные на основе сессии с логином.

Как можно улучшить и какие дыры есть в этом алгоритме?

Comment: Идентификатор сессии - это логин пользователя?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/session.security.php

Answer (score 2):

В качестве улучшения можно заглянуть в php.ini, и **поменять  алгоритм хэширования**, используемый для генерации идентификатора сессии. `'0'` означает **MD5 (128 bits)**, а `'1'` означает **SHA-1 (160 bits)**. Начиная с PHP 5.3.0 также стало возможным указать любой из алгоритмов, предусмотренных расширением `hash` (если оно доступно), например `sha512` или `whirlpool`. Полный список алгоритмов может быть получен с помощью функции `hash_algos()`.

Comment: Что хэш MD5 (128 bits) уведут, что SHA-1 (160 bits), разницы ни какой.

Comment: согласен, но это был ответ на часть вопроса "Как можно улучшить" ;)

Answer (score 0):

В алгоритме дыр нет - все достаточно надежно. Дыры если возможны только на этапе реализации.

В качестве усовершенствования можно (1) перевести страницы с формой и AJAX-обработчик формы на HTTPS - трафик будет зашифрован и его перехват не даст злоумышленнику пароль в открытом виде. (2) Для того, чтобы снизить вероятность угона сессии следует ограничить время ее действия, каким-то разумным сроком. (3) Разумеется ни в коем случае нельзя допускать XSS-инъекций на сайте, возможно стоит проверить его каким-нибудь автоматическим инструментом.

Comment: (4)  session.cookie_httponly="1", + к (1) весь сайт перевести на https и сделать session.cookie_secure="1"